# npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! syscall open npm ERR! path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path E:\Nodejs\crud\frontend\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\Nodejs\crud\frontend\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

Unable to install npm on visual studio code

I've tried it many times and I expect that npm should be installed

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your project is not initialized, or you are running npm install in the wrong folder.

`package.json`, which is the file used to perform the install, is missing. It needs to be located in your current folder when running this command.

If you are trying to initialize a project at this location, use `npm init`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you tried to practice CRUD pattern with Node.js.
I assume you missed the package.json on frontend directory.
You need to command.

```
npm --version
```

If that does not work on your vs code, then try to install npm/node on your machine

After that following commands

```
npm init -y
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly ...

In most of cases It´s occurrs when npm start is been running in wrong folder.
Check if you are in correct folder and then try run npm again.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35447310)